# Fetch NULL values in PDO query

Tags: pdo, null, fetch

I have a MySQL table with the following structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When a value is not provided, `NULL` is used as default for `image` and `price`.

```
+---------+-------+-------+
| id      | image | price |
+---------+-------+-------+
| lorem   | ipsum | NULL  |
| dolor   | NULL  | 10.20 |
+---------+-------+-------+
```

My goal is to fetch `NULL` values with a PDO query.

```
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS, PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING);
$query = $connection->query('SELECT * FROM test');
$q = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

But when I run the snippet, `NULL` values are converted to empty strings.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => dolor
            [1] => 
            [2] => 10.20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => lorem
            [1] => ipsum
            [2] => 
        )
)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try using var_dump instead of print_r to see whether the values are NULL rather than zero length strings.